# Redirect stdout from a runing script

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

In C, you can redirect stdout somewhere when a program is running, for example:

```
int fd = open("some_file", O_RDWR);
dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
printf("write to some_file\n");
```

Can I achieve this in bash without redirecting stdout when running a bash script (`./script.sh > some_file`)?

Comment: Shell redirections are implemented by inheritance before the process even starts, and you cannot subsequently alter its memory (like point to a different file) from outside. You can do things if the process is pre-written to action them (like have it re-read a config file when it gets SigInt). Best to redirect stdout to a file initially, and then dip into it with tail -f as you wish. You may want to use `stdbuf(1)` to make stdout line-buffered in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [redirection](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Redirections) around any command, including compound commands. For example:

```
some_function () {
  echo "This also $1 to the file"
}

{
  echo "This goes to the file"
  some_function "goes"
} >some_file
echo "This does not go to the file"
some_function "does not go"
```

You can do a permanent redirection (which applies until the end of the script or until overridden by another redirection) by calling the [`exec` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#index-exec) with a redirection, but no command. For example:

```
foo () {
  echo "This does not go to the file"
  exec >some_file
  echo "This goes to the file"
}
foo
echo "This still goes to the file"
```

These features are available in all Bourne/POSIX-style shells including bash.